# Click on markers Google Maps API and change page using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails and I have a good amount of markers, now when I click on a marker appears infowindow I need to click the marker and be redirected to another page.

Controller:

```
def index
@postos = Posto.all
@markers = Posto.all.to_gmaps4rails  

@json = Posto.all.to_gmaps4rails  do |posto, marker|
 marker.json "\"id\": #{posto.id}"
end  
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @postos }
  end
end
```

Javascript:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker_container.serviceObject, 'click', @openInfoWindow(currentMap, marker_container.infowindow, marker_container.serviceObject))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're almost ok but your js function seems out of subject, you should code something like:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker_container.serviceObject, 'click', function() { your_code_to_change_page_depending_on_the_marker })
```

Comment: I'm having the following error when I add the line of code mentioned in the answer: SyntaxError: reserved word "function"

Comment: This is my first rails application, I followed your youtube videos to get here, sorry for the mistakes beginners.

Comment: No problem, BTW, the screencast is really old and outdated, I should remove it.